# Eleven divided by two is two, and two plus four is seven. This is proven, it is as true as two equals three

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Seemingly the title went unnoticed, it has some important logic:

> Eleven divided by two is two, and two plus four is seven. This is proven, it is as true as two equals three

So, what is:

```
(
  five to the power of (four plus nine minus one)
  times (fourteen minus eight)
) plus (
  seven to the power of one
  plus (sixteen plus five minus two)
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see that

> The 11/2 is 2 because when you divide the number of letters you get 2 and it is the same with 2+4=7. This is when 2=3 with letters. T W O = 3.

So,

> With the other equation and the number of letters you get: (4^(4+4-3)*(8-5))+(5^3+(7+4-3)) = 3,205.

Comment: didn't check your outcome because I don't have the exact answer on me right now but your logic is correct. Well done!

Comment: Thanks, Nice puzzle :) Also welcome to Puzzling SE if you take a tour here you can get an extra badge! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:

> The word 'eleven' has six letters, and the word 'two' has three letters. 6 divided by 3 is 2.

Also,

> Two equals three, because the word 'two' has three letters in it.

Answer (score -2):

## The Three Key Clues:

> $${\Large{11\div 2 = 2}}$$ $${\Large{2+4=7}}$$ $${\Large{2=3}}$$

I believe the rule is that

> $0=1$.

Thus...

> ...you get the truthful answer and add $1$. $$11\div 2 = (1+1)\div 2 = 2\div 2 = 1\tag*{$(+1$ makes $2)$}$$ $$2+4=6\tag*{$(+1$ makes $7)$}$$ $$2=2\tag*{$(+1$ makes $3)$}$$

Therefore, we solve the entire equation $\downarrow$

> $$\begin{align}\big(5^{4+9-1}\times (14-8)\big)+7^{1+16+(5\times 2)} &= (5^{12}\times 6)+7^{17+10} \\ &= \big(\left(5^3\right)^4\times 6\big) + 7^{27} \\ &= (125^4\times 6) + 7^{27}\end{align}$$

And then...

> ...we add $1$ to every single number, making $$(126^5\times 7)+8^{28}.$$

Or...

> We add $1$ to every single number on the **left hand side** and *then* solve: $$\big(5^{4+9-1}\times (14-8)\big)+7^{1+16+(5\times 2)}\longrightarrow \big(6^{5+10-2}\times (15-7)\big)+8^{2+17+(6\times 3)}$$

which, skipping all the steps, is equal to

> $$8\times \left(6^{13}+8^{36}\right) = {\small\text{the answer on the calculator}}.$$

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie yup, just put that in :)

Comment: i edited the post, the title had the core logic of the riddle

Comment: @Jarkko it was a riddle?? Hahahh, I am favouriting this $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$